# jquery location picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm fairly new to web design and programming but I'm trying to use this [jQuery Location Picker](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/)

I'm using ASP.NET 4.6.1 C# with jQuery 3.1.1 installed. I've tried using the most basic versions with the original .js file but no luck, can't even get it to work on JSFiddle. It's probably something very simple but here's the sample on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lasttccasey/ctfhxzg6/).

```
<div id="somecomponent" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    $('#somecomponent').locationpicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Please specify "not working". I see in your fiddle that the required include of `js/locationpicker.jquery.js` is missing...

Comment: By not working I mean no map shows up when the page loads. The content in the Javascript window is the locationpicker.jquery.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be two problems.

1. You have not added the reference for `locationpicker.jquery.js` library in your `html` file.
2. You have to provide map key in your `map.js`. So generate it from the `Google Console`.

Comment: In my aspx page I have `<script src="[path]/locationpicker.jquery.js"></script>` with the correct path.
As for the `map.js` I'm not sure what that is?

Comment: you have to pass the key while loading map.ja.Check this link for reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Add either

```
$('#somecomponent').locationpicker();
```

at the end of the JavaScript code or choose **No wrap - in head** for the JavaScript load type in the JSFiddle.

This is because the `$('#somecomponent').locationpicker();` in your script tag is called before the JavaScript code with the `locationpicker()` function is loaded.

See a working snippet here:

```js
/*! jquery-locationpicker - v0.1.15 - 2016-09-26 */
(function($) {
    function GMapContext(domElement, options) {
        var _map = new google.maps.Map(domElement, options);
        var _marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.19335, -3.92695),
            map: _map,
            title: "Drag Me",
            visible: options.markerVisible,
            draggable: options.markerDraggable,
            icon: options.markerIcon !== undefined ? options.markerIcon : undefined
        });
        return {
            map: _map,
            marker: _marker,
            circle: null,
            location: _marker.position,
            radius: options.radius,
            locationName: options.locationName,
            addressComponents: {
                formatted_address: null,
                addressLine1: null,
                addressLine2: null,
                streetName: null,
                streetNumber: null,
                city: null,
                district: null,
                state: null,
                stateOrProvince: null
            },
            settings: options.settings,
            domContainer: domElement,
            geodecoder: new google.maps.Geocoder()
        };
    }
    var GmUtility = {
        drawCircle: function(gmapContext, center, radius, options) {
            if (gmapContext.circle != null) {
                gmapContext.circle.setMap(null);
            }
            if (radius > 0) {
                radius *= 1;
                options = $.extend({
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: .35,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    fillOpacity: .2
                }, options);
                options.map = gmapContext.map;
                options.radius = radius;
                options.center = center;
                gmapContext.circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
                return gmapContext.circle;
            }
            return null;
        },
        setPosition: function(gMapContext, location, callback) {
            gMapContext.location = location;
            gMapContext.marker.setPosition(location);
            gMapContext.map.panTo(location);
            this.drawCircle(gMapContext, location, gMapContext.radius, {});
            if (gMapContext.settings.enableReverseGeocode) {
                this.updateLocationName(gMapContext, callback);
            } else {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.call(this, gMapContext);
                }
            }
        },
        locationFromLatLng: function(lnlg) {
            return {
                latitude: lnlg.lat(),
                longitude: lnlg.lng()
            };
        },
        addressByFormat: function(addresses, format) {
            var result = null;
            for (var i = addresses.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (addresses[i].types.indexOf(format) >= 0) {
                    result = addresses[i];
                }
            }
            return result || addresses[0];
        },
        updateLocationName: function(gmapContext, callback) {
            gmapContext.geodecoder.geocode({
                latLng: gmapContext.marker.position
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                    var address = GmUtility.addressByFormat(results, gmapContext.settings.addressFormat);
                    gmapContext.locationName = address.formatted_address;
                    gmapContext.addressComponents = GmUtility.address_component_from_google_geocode(address.address_components);
                } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    return setTimeout(function() {
                        GmUtility.updateLocationName(gmapContext, callback);
                    }, 1e3);
                }
                if (callback) {
                    callback.call(this, gmapContext);
                }
            });
        },
        address_component_from_google_geocode: function(address_components) {
            var result = {};
            for (var i = address_components.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var component = address_components[i];
                if (component.types.indexOf("postal_code") >= 0) {
                    result.postalCode = component.short_name;
                } else if (component.types.indexOf("street_number") >= 0) {
                    result.streetNumber = component.short_name;
                } else if (component.types.indexOf("route") >= 0) {
                    result.streetName = component.short_name;
                } else if (component.types.indexOf("locality") >= 0) {
                    result.city = component.short_name;
                } else if (component.types.indexOf("sublocality") >= 0) {
                    result.district = component.short_name;
                } else if (component.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") >= 0) {
                    result.stateOrProvince = component.short_name;
                } else if (component.types.indexOf("country") >= 0) {
                    result.country = component.short_name;
                }
            }
            result.addressLine1 = [ result.streetNumber, result.streetName ].join(" ").trim();
            result.addressLine2 = "";
            return result;
        }
    };
    function isPluginApplied(domObj) {
        return getContextForElement(domObj) != undefined;
    }
    function getContextForElement(domObj) {
        return $(domObj).data("locationpicker");
    }
    function updateInputValues(inputBinding, gmapContext) {
        if (!inputBinding) return;
        var currentLocation = GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(gmapContext.marker.position);
        if (inputBinding.latitudeInput) {
            inputBinding.latitudeInput.val(currentLocation.latitude).change();
        }
        if (inputBinding.longitudeInput) {
            inputBinding.longitudeInput.val(currentLocation.longitude).change();
        }
        if (inputBinding.radiusInput) {
            inputBinding.radiusInput.val(gmapContext.radius).change();
        }
        if (inputBinding.locationNameInput) {
            inputBinding.locationNameInput.val(gmapContext.locationName).change();
        }
    }
    function setupInputListenersInput(inputBinding, gmapContext) {
        if (inputBinding) {
            if (inputBinding.radiusInput) {
                inputBinding.radiusInput.on("change", function(e) {
                    var radiusInputValue = $(this).val();
                    if (!e.originalEvent || isNaN(radiusInputValue)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    gmapContext.radius = radiusInputValue;
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, gmapContext.location, function(context) {
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                    });
                });
            }
            if (inputBinding.locationNameInput && gmapContext.settings.enableAutocomplete) {
                var blur = false;
                gmapContext.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputBinding.locationNameInput.get(0), gmapContext.settings.autocompleteOptions);
                google.maps.event.addListener(gmapContext.autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
                    blur = false;
                    var place = gmapContext.autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        gmapContext.settings.onlocationnotfound(place.name);
                        return;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, place.geometry.location, function(context) {
                        updateInputValues(inputBinding, context);
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                    });
                });
                if (gmapContext.settings.enableAutocompleteBlur) {
                    inputBinding.locationNameInput.on("change", function(e) {
                        if (!e.originalEvent) {
                            return;
                        }
                        blur = true;
                    });
                    inputBinding.locationNameInput.on("blur", function(e) {
                        if (!e.originalEvent) {
                            return;
                        }
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var address = $(inputBinding.locationNameInput).val();
                            if (address.length > 5 && blur) {
                                blur = false;
                                gmapContext.geodecoder.geocode({
                                    address: address
                                }, function(results, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results && results.length) {
                                        GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, results[0].geometry.location, function(context) {
                                            updateInputValues(inputBinding, context);
                                            context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }, 1e3);
                    });
                }
            }
            if (inputBinding.latitudeInput) {
                inputBinding.latitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
                    var latitudeInputValue = $(this).val();
                    if (!e.originalEvent || isNaN(latitudeInputValue)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeInputValue, gmapContext.location.lng()), function(context) {
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                        updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    });
                });
            }
            if (inputBinding.longitudeInput) {
                inputBinding.longitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
                    var longitudeInputValue = $(this).val();
                    if (!e.originalEvent || isNaN(longitudeInputValue)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(gmapContext.location.lat(), longitudeInputValue), function(context) {
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                        updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
    function autosize(gmapContext) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmapContext.map, "resize");
        setTimeout(function() {
            gmapContext.map.setCenter(gmapContext.marker.position);
        }, 300);
    }
    function updateMap(gmapContext, $target, options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.locationpicker.defaults, options), latNew = settings.location.latitude, lngNew = settings.location.longitude, radiusNew = settings.radius, latOld = gmapContext.settings.location.latitude, lngOld = gmapContext.settings.location.longitude, radiusOld = gmapContext.settings.radius;
        if (latNew == latOld && lngNew == lngOld && radiusNew == radiusOld) return;
        gmapContext.settings.location.latitude = latNew;
        gmapContext.settings.location.longitude = lngNew;
        gmapContext.radius = radiusNew;
        GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(gmapContext.settings.location.latitude, gmapContext.settings.location.longitude), function(context) {
            setupInputListenersInput(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
            context.settings.oninitialized($target);
        });
    }
    $.fn.locationpicker = function(options, params) {
        if (typeof options == "string") {
            var _targetDomElement = this.get(0);
            if (!isPluginApplied(_targetDomElement)) return;
            var gmapContext = getContextForElement(_targetDomElement);
            switch (options) {
              case "location":
                if (params == undefined) {
                    var location = GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(gmapContext.location);
                    location.radius = gmapContext.radius;
                    location.name = gmapContext.locationName;
                    return location;
                } else {
                    if (params.radius) {
                        gmapContext.radius = params.radius;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(params.latitude, params.longitude), function(gmapContext) {
                        updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    });
                }
                break;

              case "subscribe":
                if (params == undefined) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    var event = params.event;
                    var callback = params.callback;
                    if (!event || !callback) {
                        console.error('LocationPicker: Invalid arguments for method "subscribe"');
                        return null;
                    }
                    google.maps.event.addListener(gmapContext.map, event, callback);
                }
                break;

              case "map":
                if (params == undefined) {
                    var locationObj = GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(gmapContext.location);
                    locationObj.formattedAddress = gmapContext.locationName;
                    locationObj.addressComponents = gmapContext.addressComponents;
                    return {
                        map: gmapContext.map,
                        marker: gmapContext.marker,
                        location: locationObj
                    };
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

              case "autosize":
                autosize(gmapContext);
                return this;
            }
            return null;
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            var $target = $(this);
            if (isPluginApplied(this)) {
                updateMap(getContextForElement(this), $(this), options);
                return;
            }
            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.locationpicker.defaults, options);
            var gmapContext = new GMapContext(this, $.extend({}, settings.mapOptions, {
                zoom: settings.zoom,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(settings.location.latitude, settings.location.longitude),
                mapTypeId: settings.mapTypeId,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                styles: settings.styles,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
                scrollwheel: settings.scrollwheel,
                streetViewControl: false,
                radius: settings.radius,
                locationName: settings.locationName,
                settings: settings,
                autocompleteOptions: settings.autocompleteOptions,
                addressFormat: settings.addressFormat,
                draggable: settings.draggable,
                markerIcon: settings.markerIcon,
                markerDraggable: settings.markerDraggable,
                markerVisible: settings.markerVisible
            }));
            $target.data("locationpicker", gmapContext);
            function displayMarkerWithSelectedArea() {
                GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, gmapContext.marker.position, function(context) {
                    var currentLocation = GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(gmapContext.location);
                    updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ currentLocation, context.radius, true ]);
                });
            }
            if (settings.markerInCenter) {
                gmapContext.map.addListener("bounds_changed", function() {
                    if (!gmapContext.marker.dragging) {
                        gmapContext.marker.setPosition(gmapContext.map.center);
                        updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    }
                });
                gmapContext.map.addListener("idle", function() {
                    if (!gmapContext.marker.dragging) {
                        displayMarkerWithSelectedArea();
                    }
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addListener(gmapContext.marker, "drag", function(event) {
                updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(gmapContext.marker, "dragend", function(event) {
                displayMarkerWithSelectedArea();
            });
            GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(settings.location.latitude, settings.location.longitude), function(context) {
                updateInputValues(settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                setupInputListenersInput(settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                context.settings.oninitialized($target);
            });
        });
    };
    $.fn.locationpicker.defaults = {
        location: {
            latitude: 40.7324319,
            longitude: -73.82480777777776
        },
        locationName: "",
        radius: 500,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [],
        mapOptions: {},
        scrollwheel: true,
        inputBinding: {
            latitudeInput: null,
            longitudeInput: null,
            radiusInput: null,
            locationNameInput: null
        },
        enableAutocomplete: false,
        enableAutocompleteBlur: false,
        autocompleteOptions: null,
        addressFormat: "postal_code",
        enableReverseGeocode: true,
        draggable: true,
        onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {},
        onlocationnotfound: function(locationName) {},
        oninitialized: function(component) {},
        markerIcon: undefined,
        markerDraggable: true,
        markerVisible: true
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#somecomponent').locationpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="somecomponent" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: This works for JSFiddle, but when trying to implement it to my site I'm still not getting the map to load. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @MuffinMan I don't know how to answer that because I don't know what you're doing different from the JSFiddle example. So my advice is to double check the [usage instructions](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/) and look for error messages in your browsers console.

Comment: @MuffinMan I just simply copied the html source code from the page http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/ to my own webserver and the included locationpicker worked instantly.